# Vertical buttons with equal width

Tags: css, button, width

It's two vertical arrangement buttons. I need them to be of equal width.
I don't know:

- what size will on wrap;
- what text will appear on buttons (therefore I can't use pixel width);
- what width will on buttons.

Buttons must be at left. Text on buttons must be center-aligned. I can't use 100% width cause it will not beauty :)

I can't use flexbox and specify width to buttons. And will be cool a solution on pure CSS.

IE8+

```css
.wrap{
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.btn{
    height 40px;
    background-color: tomato;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="btn">small button</button>
  <button class="btn">super long button</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you explain the "can't use 100% width cause it will not beauty"? Thanks

Comment: if wrap will 1000px, buttons with 100% width will be 1000px too. It's not beauty design

Comment: Ah - you mean from a design perspective it doesn't look good, fair comment :) Does @Pete answer fix your problem? If so, please accept his answer using the tick under the voting arrows

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just make the container inline-block and then the buttons 100% width, that way they will take the width of the largest button:

```css
.wrap{
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid red;
}

.btn{
    height 40px;
    background-color: tomato;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    display: block;
    width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <button class="btn">small button</button>
  <button class="btn">super long button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `inline-block` for your container div!

Comment: This is not really an answer, in it's current state it would probably be better as a comment. Please add more details and code examples.